# What is needed to use notify-send in a snap?

Tags: snap, notify-send

I use `notify-send` in a python program, and I'm trying to make a snap of that program. The snap builds but I get a

```
No such file or directory 'notify-send'
```

What package do I need to install to make notify-send work?

I thought I needed to do

```
plug: [x11]
```

in my snapcraft.yaml but it didn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we need to add this to the snapcraft.yaml file:

```
stage-packages:
    - libnotify-bin
```